# "What's" in indirect questions

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, indirect-question, wh-questions

Lets consider the following:

> The book doesn't explain, "What's the wisdom behind education?"

Changing this to an indirect question becomes the following:

> The book doesn't explain what the wisdom behind education is.

Now, I found many instances on Google where structures like this weren't really converted to indirect questions. For example:

> The book doesn't explain what's the wisdom behind education.
>
> "[She] doesn't say what's really on her mind."

Edit:

And consider the following:

> What's the logic behind it.
>
> (a) I wonder what's the logic behind it vs. (b)I wonder what the logic behind it is.

(a) sounds better but why?
And are these constructions acceptable?

Comment: Your example is a little confusing to me. Do you mean (a) The book doesn't _ask_, "What's the wisdom behind education?" or (b) The book doesn't _answer_, "What's the wisdom behind education?" (When I initially read your first quote, I assumed you meant (a), but after I read the second quote, I began to wonder if you meant (b) instead.)  As for the third way you phrase it, that may be an acceptable construction, but it still reads awkwardly; I'd be inclined to get rid of the "what's", and use a more precise verb than "say": "The book doesn't _explain_ the wisdom behind education."

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81568/asking-someone-to-let-you-know-something

Comment: @J.R.: Fixed those.Thanks for the input. Sorry for not properly analyzing them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“I'm not sure what the right way is”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is) Also related: [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, the last two examples are quite different. In the first example, *what* substitutes the predicative

> The wisdom behind education is **something**.
>
> **What** is the wisdom behind education? (question is about the predicative)
>
> I don't know **what** the wisdom behind education **is**. <-- correct
>
> <s>I don't know what is the wisdom behind education.</s> <-- too colloquial, unacceptable in formal writing.

Now, in the second example, *what* substitutes the subject.

> **Something** is on her mind.
>
> **What** is on her mind? (question is about the subject)
>
> I don't know **what is** on her mind. <-- correct
>
> <s>I don't know what on her mind is</s> <-- incorrect

Comment: So if I say: *what's the logic behind it*, should it become: *I wonder what's the logic behind it*, or *I wonder what the logic behind it is*. The first sounds better to me, but I cant untangle the grammatical details.

Comment: @Noah: You should use the second. It's the same pattern as your example

Comment: @Noah: You should say _I wonder "What's the logic behind it?"_ or _I wonder what the logic behind it is._

Answer (score 6):

The difference between embedded and non-embedded questions is that, while normal *Wh*-questions must undergo [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69847/15299), in certain cases,

> -- though, note, **only** in those cases; we'll return to this point later --

- *What did the man eat?*
- **What the man ate?*

embedded *Wh*-questions normally don't in these cases.

- *I don't know what the man ate.*
- **I don't know what did the man eat.*

However, this distinction is moot in

- *I wonder what's on her mind.*

because this is **not** one of those "certain cases" in which Subject-Auxiliary Inversion is required. The case where it **is** required in normal *Wh*-questions is the case in which the *Wh*-questioned word is the subject of the question.

Swapping the verb with the subject is designed to put something other than a normal NP at the beginning of a question to show that it's a question. In a *Yes/No*-question, that's the auxiliary verb. But in a *Wh*-question, there's also a *Wh*-word, which is a question marker all by itself, and when it's the subject, it's **already** at the beginning of the question, marking it as a question.

So, in that case, as Armen points out, no inversion is necessary in a normal *Wh*-question

- *What's on her mind?*

and therefore it's not necessary either in an embedded *Wh*-question

- *I don't know what's on her mind.*

Comment: Plus, of course, once an auxiliary is contracted, it's not available for inversion anyway. _What's_ is frozen and can't be resplit. Same reason people say _There's 11 men on a football team_; once _there's_ is contracted, it's not available for number agreement any more.

Answer (score 2):

There's an inconsistency in the preamble. One has to be very careful when converting a quote structure to a report structure:

**The book doesn't say, "What's the wisdom behind education?"**

Changing this to an indirect question becomes the following:

**The book doesn't ask what the wisdom behind education is.**

This conversion largely preserves sense, but even now, the reported version may be an inaccurate statement while the quote version may be an accurate if pedantic one - the actual wording in the book might be "What is the wisdom behind education?", for instance.

Addressing the problem about the grammatical (rather than semantic) correctness of various report structures, the tendency is for much less rigid rules to be deemed necessary for both the wording and the punctuation, with the proviso that accuracy be maintained and ambiguity be avoided.

For instance, I've come across (on the web) examples of the use of *bid* and *wish* both as reporting verbs proper and quote verbs:

He bade us a fond farewell.
He bade us welcome.

... bade us "Goodbye" [unusual]

She wished us a merry Christmas.
She wished us Merry Christmas.

She wished us "Merry Christmas."

There may be other verbs used in both capacities.
(Say appears to be, of course:

He said {that} she was going shopping.
He said "She was going shopping."

but the meaning changes slightly.)

With the examples given, I'd say that

**The book doesn't say what's the wisdom behind education.** or **The book doesn't ask what's the wisdom behind education.** are clumsy elisions, better expressed as **The book doesn't say what the wisdom behind education is.** or **The book doesn't ask what the wisdom behind education is.** (the difference is now obvious).

However, **"[She] doesn't say what's really on her mind."** is quite acceptable grammatically, in fact the accepted idiomatic expression. Though I'm struggling to think of the related quote version.

Answer (score 1):

As for the question edit:

> What's the logic behind it.
>
> *(a) I wonder what's the logic behind it*
>   *(b) I wonder what the logic behind it is.*
>
> (a) sounds better but why? And are these constructions acceptable?

(b) is correct. In fact, I used to have the same doubt, then I found this:

> How's he handling the issue. *(similar sentence structure)*
>
> (a) I wonder how's he handling the issue
>   (b) I wonder how he's handling the issue

It's not exactly the same, but it made me grasp the concept easily.

Answer (score 0):

OK... Consider this:

- I wonder what´s the language they speak. (among many languages)
- I wonder what the language they speak is. (sounds weird once nobody needs to define language)

It helps me grasp...

[Edited for layout]

Comment: Or more simply: I wonder what language they speak?