# the auxiliary “need” (in affirmative sentences?)

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, bare-infinitive, semi-modals

I remember being told the modal “need” is used only in interrogative and negative sentences and was for quite a long time more idiomatic than the normal forms, but is there anything wrong with the following examples, in which “need” can seemingly be replaced with “must”?

> 1. All you need do is ask.
> 2. He wonders if he need go.
> 3. In order to pass the course you need pass the exam.

Is the only crime here some awkwardness, or are these ungrammatical?

Thank you!

Comment: [Semi-modal _need_ and _dare_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69847/15299) are [negative polarity items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf); that is, they can only occur in negative environments, which includes questions and _if_ clauses. That explains why (1-2) are grammatical. (3) is ungrammatical, however, since that clause isn't a negative environment.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you, I had never heard of “negative polarity items,” but the first isn’t a question, so does the pronoun “all,” because it means “the only thing,” introduce a negative environment?

Comment: So I can write, “In order to pass the course you need only pass the exam,” but have to find another word for example three above?

Comment: Yes, _only_ is a negative trigger. But adding _only_ changes the meaning somewhat.