# Infinitive without to

Tags: grammar, infinitives

What's the difference between" You need stay at home" and " You need to stay at home"? It seems to me that the former one talks about things that someone ought to do as responsibility. Yet, the latter one talks about things that someone needs to do in the future, not at the present. Would appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Is "You need stay at home" the **complete** sentence you're asking about? Or is it something like "...whether you need stay at home..."?

Answer (score 4):

- **You **need** stay at home* is an ungrammatical sentence.

*Need,* like *dare,* is a [semi-modal verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20semi%20modal). That means it can act like a [Modal Auxiliary verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/570947/15299) in certain situations, of which this is not one. When it **does** act like a modal auxiliary verb, it can take an infinitive without *to*; that's what modal auxiliary verbs like *must, can,* and *would* do:

- *You **must** stay at home; she **can** stay at home; I **would** stay at home.*

So, when do semi-modal verbs get to act  like modals?
In negative contexts. Semi-modality is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69847/15299), like *ever* or *budge*

- *He sat down and didn't budge for an hour,* but not **He budged for a while*
- *He doesn't ever go down there,* but not **He ever goes down there*
- *You need not stay at home,* but not **You need stay at home*
- *He dare not tell the story,* but not **He dare tell the story*

When semi-modals don't occur in a negative environment, they just take infinitives with *to*, like most verbs; it's only with negation that they do tricks.

Comment: I think would be valid if "stay at home" was nouned. But then, it would probably take hyphens : "You need stay-at-home". And it would be more idiomatic to say "You need some stay-at-home"